# Is it possible to obtain the local defintion from the global definition, in Topology?

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible to obtain the local defintion from the global definition, in Topology?

We have the following properties:

- connectedness
- path-connectedness
- being a bases
- compact
- etc..

Each of these definitions also has a local and global defintion. But is it possible to obtain the local defintion from the global definition? Or vice versa, going from the local defintion to the global defintion? (Or should I learn both the global and local defintions by heart?)

I'm having trouble seeing the pattern of connection between the local and global defintions.

Regards,
Jens

Comment: Can you give the local and global definitions of compactness as an example?

Comment: @TonyS.F. [Locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) and [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).

Comment: When I teach topology we discuss this exact question, with the conclusion that while there are some patterns, they are not entirely consistent, and you really do need to know each "local" definition on its own terms.

Comment: @LeeMosher : isn't "$X$ is locally P" defined as "any $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood basis consisting of sets that are P [with the induced topology]" ?

Comment: @Max I wonder. For example local connectedness requires that every open neighbourhood has an open connected sub-neighbourhood. Can that be derived from your definition? Note that neighbourhoods need not be open. On the other hand if you assume that neighbourhoods are open then it fails for compactness.

Comment: @freakish you are right, and I believe it doesn't work for locally connected. But can someone give an example where neither the definition I gave, nor the same one with "consisting of *open* sets ..." works ? If there is no such example, it would bring down the problem to choosing between two definitions which could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

> But is it possible to obtain the local defintion from the global definition?

Sort of. One recurring pattern is the following:

> **$X$ is locally $P$ at $x\in X$** if for any open neighbourhood $x\in U\subseteq X$ there is an open neighbourhood $x\in V\subseteq U$ such that $V$ has $P$.
>
> **$X$ is locally $P$** if it is locally $P$ at every point.

This however fails for local compactness where we require that "$\overline{V}$ has $P$" not "$V$ has $P$" (proper open subsets are rarely compact, never in connected Hausdorff case).

Things become even more complicated in non-Hausdorff case where different definitions of local compactness are not equivalent. Indeed, [there is more then one definition of local compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space#Formal_definition).

> Or should I learn both the global and local defintions by heart?

At the end of the day that's the only reliable way.